# ayuda no envia el correo php

Tags: php

hola buen dia lo que pasa es que estoy generando un sistema para enviar correos segun yo ya tengo todo bien pero a la hora de enviar ejecuta todo pero no hace lo que debe hacer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Formulario de contacto</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="enviar.php" method="POST">

      <h2>CONTACTO</h2>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
      <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
      <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe aqui: " `required>`</textarea>`
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="boton">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el codigo que recibe los valores para poder mandarlo supuestamente

```
     <?php
 $destino="juannigthlord@gmail.com";
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $correo = $_POST["correo"];
 $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
 $contenido = "Nombre: " .$nombre . "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
 if ( mail($destino,"Fallo", $mensaje) ) 
 { echo "Mensaje enviado"; } 
 else { echo error_get_last()['message']; } 

?>
```

mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Tienes un  backtick al final de `$contenido` ,prueba a borrarlo, de modo que quede así: **`$contenido = "Nombre: " .$nombre . "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nMensaje: " 
 .$mensaje;`**

Comment: ya lo hice asi como me lo mandaste pero no me sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Sale algún error en los logs?

Comment: Intenta capturar el error, prueba así: **`$contenido = "Nombre: $nombre  \nCorreo: $correo. \nMensaje: $mensaje";
     if ( mail($destino,"Fallo", $mensaje) ) { echo "Mensaje enviado"; } else {
    echo error_get_last()['message']; }`** Y, **sigo viendo el backtick** en tu código aún después de haber editado la pregunta.

Comment: listo editado y con el codigo nuevo

Comment: ¿Qué sale ahora?

Comment: eso el mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Ok, no me fijé en la edición de la pregunta. Puede que el error se deba a que no tienes un servidor de email instalado en tu equipo local, entonces tendrías que instalar alguno o en el `php.ini` indicar como servidor smtp el de Gmail. O puede que tengas el servidor de email, pero no esté bien seteado en el `php.ini`. ¿Piensas mandar emails vía PHP desde tu localhost` o es para usar el script en una web?

Comment: [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25

Comment: la verda lo pienso cargar en un servidor pero ahorita esta en modo pruebas para que acepte correos de cualquier dominio

Comment: El problema de enviar correos con `mail()` desde localhost es un viejo conocido. Se requiere tener un servidor de email instalado en tu equipo local o pasar por otras soluciones de configuración que pueden variar según el entorno. Si es para subirlo a un servidor no vale la pena complicarte, el código que tienes funcionará sin problema, porque el servidor tiene su servidor de correo. Otra posibilidad seria que lo hagas con `PHPMailer`
.

Comment: ok entonces pero si quiero hacer pruebas locales entonces como lo configuro para poder enviar